# TortoiseSVN flagging DLLs as changed that haven't changed

Tags: svn, dll, tortoisesvn

A co-worker rebuilt our project in Visual Studio 2010 and Tortoise flagged all the DLLs attached to it as changed, but none of them were changed.  Is there a way to "void" this status on these.  Personally, I would just tell Tortoise to ignore DLLs, but apparently we are supposed to keep them in the repository.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the files have changed. Not the way the dlls behave, but the dll files have changed: they contain among other info also the date they were build.

So as far as SVN is concerned: the files **were** changed.

Comment: That is exactly what I was thinking too, but I wanted to make sure there wasn't something odd going on.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the following and it took care of our issue:

Third party libraries

When there are third party libraries stored in the working copy directly, i.e., not via the svn:externals property, then updating those is not quite easy.

Just copying over the new version will work of course, but if the new version has files removed, those files will still be in your working copy.

In version 1.8 TortoiseSVN offers an easier way to do this: just right-drag the folder with the new version of the library to the version stored in your working copy, then select SVN vendor branch here

from the context menu.  TortoiseSVN then scans both directories, copies all new files, removes files that are not present anymore in the new version.

After TortoiseSVN updated the folder, all you have to do is commit the new version.